# Can Internet Explorer use the AES crytographic algorithm for HTTPS?

Tags: apache, https, security, internet-explorer

I wanted to disable RC4 and "force" PFS on my website. Without modification, every browser used RC4. As I don't have access to the root directory I did it by modifying the .htaccess file. Note: The server currently only supports TLS 1.0.

So I changed the CipherSuite to:

```
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
```

Which worked fine on every browser, but the IE, which "can't find the address". So I tried it with:

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:DH+AES:!MD5
```

Same result here. Just to test if it would work with RC4 i tried it with:

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:DH+AES:RC4-SHA:!MD5
```

After this modification, all browsers use AES as cipher. IE now displays the page, but uses RC4 as cipher, even though it should support AES.

So, does IE support anything but RC4? I tried to test this with:

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:-RC4
```

Again it can't connect. But: AES works fine on Google/Youtube (TLS 1.2).

I tested it on multiple versions of IE and Windows and got the same result every time I tried to connect.

Am I missing something obvious here? Is there anyone who knows why IE won't display my website? Or is my code just completely wrong?

Here a list of my supported ciphersuites for reference:

```
[~]openssl ciphers -v
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
AECDH-AES256-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ADH-AES256-SHA          SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
CAMELLIA256-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(256) Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
AECDH-DES-CBC3-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ADH-DES-CBC3-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
DES-CBC3-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
DES-CBC3-MD5            SSLv2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=MD5
PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
AECDH-AES128-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ADH-AES128-SHA          SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ADH-SEED-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA   SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
SEED-SHA                SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=SEED(128) Mac=SHA1
CAMELLIA128-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=Camellia(128) Mac=SHA1
IDEA-CBC-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=IDEA(128) Mac=SHA1
IDEA-CBC-MD5            SSLv2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=IDEA(128) Mac=MD5
RC2-CBC-MD5             SSLv2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=RC2(128)  Mac=MD5
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA       SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
AECDH-RC4-SHA           SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=None Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
ADH-RC4-MD5             SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=MD5
ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA        SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
RC4-SHA                 SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
RC4-MD5                 SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=MD5
RC4-MD5                 SSLv2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=MD5
PSK-RC4-SHA             SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=RC4(128)  Mac=SHA1
EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=DES(56)   Mac=SHA1
EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=DES(56)   Mac=SHA1
ADH-DES-CBC-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=None Enc=DES(56)   Mac=SHA1
DES-CBC-SHA             SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=DES(56)   Mac=SHA1
DES-CBC-MD5             SSLv2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=DES(56)   Mac=MD5
EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH(512)  Au=RSA  Enc=DES(40)   Mac=SHA1 export
EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=DH(512)  Au=DSS  Enc=DES(40)   Mac=SHA1 export
EXP-ADH-DES-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH(512)  Au=None Enc=DES(40)   Mac=SHA1 export
EXP-DES-CBC-SHA         SSLv3 Kx=RSA(512) Au=RSA  Enc=DES(40)   Mac=SHA1 export
EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5         SSLv3 Kx=RSA(512) Au=RSA  Enc=RC2(40)   Mac=MD5  export
EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5         SSLv2 Kx=RSA(512) Au=RSA  Enc=RC2(40)   Mac=MD5  export
EXP-ADH-RC4-MD5         SSLv3 Kx=DH(512)  Au=None Enc=RC4(40)   Mac=MD5  export
EXP-RC4-MD5             SSLv3 Kx=RSA(512) Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(40)   Mac=MD5  export
EXP-RC4-MD5             SSLv2 Kx=RSA(512) Au=RSA  Enc=RC4(40)   Mac=MD5  export
```

Answer (score 1):

Qualys® SSL Labs offer an [SSL client testsuite](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html) which also shows all the ciphersuites a connecting user agent supports.

I don’t have “standard” MS Internet Explorer systems handy, but I know it depends on three things:

- The version and configuration of MSIE
- The version and configuration of the OS
- The version and configuration of SChannel (Windows’ built-in OpenSSL equivalent)

So, please just use your particular MSIE, head to that page, and look at whether an AES ciphersuite is among the ones offered.

Answer (score 1):

AES is supported in Schannel (the crypto library used by IE) in Windows Vista/2008 and later. It is *not* supported in XP/2003 (which, by the time you read this, nobody anywhere should be using, although some lunatics still are).

Microsoft publishes a [complete list of cipher suites available in Schannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374757(v=vs.85).aspx). And you may also want [recommended cipher suite configurations](https://cipherli.st/) for popular web servers.